# I want to get notified about upvotes and downvotes, even after I hit the reputation cap

Tags: feature-request, daily-reputation-limit

After I hit the daily reputation cap, I still want to get notified about up and downvotes from other users to my questions and answers. It stops me from getting feedback to my answers. Now, I have to go manually to all the answer and see if the score changed.

I would love to see it like this (4th element in the list):

[image]

Where the 2 ↑ represents the number of upvotes after reaching the cap.

Comment: You can also see them in your reputation feed as votes without a score, but I do agree that this would be a nice change.

Comment: I would also like to see this, but I am unsure how it would be facilitated on the upvote side. Especially considering that the achievements modal groups by reputation total, it would be hard to figure out how to show +0 there since the grouping totals wouldn't be affected and merely changing the order would probably not be much different than it already is.

Comment: @TravisJ: I was thinking about something like I added to my question.

Comment: A related issue: it's hard to get notifications of people voting on your answers on sitewide metas, because they don't change your reputation (and the reputation change is the normal way to be notified of a vote). This is awkward because knowing about votes on sitewide metas is often more important that knowing about votes on the actual site, because they let you know whether your suggestion has community consensus or not.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative: you can go to your reputation tab instead. Upvotes (and downvotes) that happened after the cap is hit will be shown without a `+<something>` score to the left.

[image]

By refreshing this page from time to time you will get the updates you want. (they're ordered chronologically on the day itself).

I do agree it would be nice to get actual notifications though. Perhaps just making the icon green instead of the usual +10?

Answer (score 3):

You could try a notification extension like [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-6-alpha-f) and see if you get notified even after hitting the rep cap.